# how to test flash cs5 app on the iPad

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, flash-cs5.5

I have created an iPad app using Flash cs5.5, how do I test on my iPad, I do have the developer cert and license.

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean by 'testing'? deploy there or debug it on the iPad?

Comment: Yes I want to debug on my iPad, thanks

Comment: i do not think you can debug it and see all traces. what i can suggest you to do is to create some LOG file, where you will put all what was happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around again, I managed to find this on the adobe website

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/index.html